# Windows disk write - does short write fill whole cluster?

Tags: windows, forensics, storage, deletion

Suppose I have a Windows program that writes to a hard disk. The hard disk has physical sectors of 512 byte length.

These sectors are accessed as clusters of 4 kilobytes each. Therefore, each cluster has 8 sectors.

Suppose I write content to that cluster that will fill it with just 2 kilobytes. So I will reliably fill the first four sectors with the content of my write buffer.

What happens to the final four sectors of the cluster I wrote to, after my write operation?

Do they get overwritten as part of the write operation, or do they remain untouched?

I realize that the answer might be "it depends". I'm mostly interested in some kind of reference information that might describe how the process is guaranteed to work.

It's the kind of thing you can test and make observations about. But it is much more difficult to "prove a negative" (that the back 4 sectors of a cluster can never remain untouched after the write)

I am also interested in other random access storage devices (eg USB flash drive, Virtual Hard Disk, SSD). But even an answer just for a hard disk would be useful.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a security question. Is there a security angle you are worried about?

Comment: @schroeder  Thanks for your interest in the question. Yes, it relates to a secure erase implementation.

Comment: If an algorithm is attempting to overwrite a series of clusters, and meanwhile one of the clusters gets written by another process on the system - has the cluster been fully overwritten or potentially just partially?

Comment: Ok, I get you, but your core question is not a security question. You intend to use the answer for security purposes, but the question itself is not a security question.

Comment: Should this question be asked elsewhere on the Stack Exchange network instead? If so, where?

Comment: short answer is yes - I'm not sure where and I've been trying to figure that out

Comment: You could revamp your question into a security one by attempting the erase itself.  Otherwise I believe it is a superuser question, if there is a Windows community it is superuser.

Comment: @grochmal   Yes. I will probably rewrite with a different emphasis and post it again at some point.

I thought the philosophy of asking questions here was to make them as focused and minimal in their scope as possible. At least the Stack Overflow forum seems to want that. So I made a point of doing that in this case.

If I widen the question to give context about the entire algorithm, it may get more engagement, and it will also be clear it's being posted in the right place.